# How to pass scope to my ajax callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, spring

I am having 3rd dropdowns.Based on first dropdown I am displaying 2nd dropdown.Based on 2nd dropdown  I am displaying 3rd one. All are Dynamic dropdowns. On page refresh my dropdown are not having values.

My question is there any chance to set the scope to my restcall or callback function..

This is my code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#customerDetails").change(function() {
        var value1 = $('#customerDetails :selected').text();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'environments',
            data : {
                selectedcustomername : value1
            },
            success : function(result) {
                getEnvNames(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my controller code,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/environments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getEnvironmentNames(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam String selectedcustomername) throws SQLException {
    request.setAttribute("selectedcustomername", selectedcustomername);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("environments", new Environments());
    List<Environments>  environmentnamesList= loginDelegate.getEnvironments(selectedcustomername);
    Collections.sort(environmentnamesList, new CustomComparator());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println("gson"+gson);
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(environmentnamesList);
    System.out.println("jsonString"+jsonString);
    return jsonString;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expecting you mean context by saying scope. You can change the success function slightly to achieve this,

```
Success :getEnvNames.bind(contextYouWant),
```

And you mean adding a scope inside success function can be done using,

```
with Statement
with(scope){}
```

Comment: Can you  tell me detailed.